# Python errno.ESTALE

Tags: python

I am getting python errno.ESTALE error on red hat5.4 NFSv3 with cache enabled.

I looked up and found that:
"A filehandle becomes stale whenever the file or directory referenced by the handle is removed by another host, while your client still holds an active reference to the object. A typical example occurs when the current directory of a process, running on your client, is removed on the server (either by a process running on the server or on another client)."

I found it that if you chown or listdir, etc. you can flush the cache and hence it wont be stale but this approch hasnt worked for me.

Anyone have other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is NFS and you are running a client on Linux.
You should try to remount your NFS filesystem.

like this:

```
$ mount -o remount [your filesystem]
```

also you could try to flush the cache as you mentioned.

```
# To free pagecache
$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

# To free dentries and inodes
$ echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

# To free pagecache, dentries and inodes
$ echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```